# useNavigate hook react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to use useNavigate hook seems that it's not working can't figure out what it needs more current react-router-dom versions that i use.  react-router@6.3.0 `-- react-router-dom@6.3.0`   -- react-router@6.3.0  Current react-router versions. Error: Error: useNavigate may be used only in the context of a Router component

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function LandingPage(props) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const auth = getAuth();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    async function preventDefault(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(email, password)
        try {
            const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            console.log(userCredential.user)
            console.log('Authorized')
            navigate('/homepage')
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            alert(err.message);
            console.log('Not Authorized')
        }
    }

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <form>
                    <h3>Login Here</h3>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Sigh up with email" id="username" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} ></input>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <button className='button' type="submit" onClick={preventDefault} >Log In</button>
                    <div className='landingpage-logo'>
                        <img src={logo} className="landingpage-logo"></img>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default LandingPage;


import LandingPage from "./components/LandingPage/LandingPage";
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeScreen from "./components/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {


  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <LandingPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/homepage">
        <HomeScreen />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: navigate.push('/homepage)

Comment: Or do something like this: const LandingPage: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => { Your code here }

Answer (score 2):

## Issues

From what I can tell, there's a `Router` component wrapping the `App` component's code, ***but*** there appears to be multiple routers. In `react-router-dom@6` only a single router/routing context is necessary. Remove all nested `Router` components.

None of the `Route` components are being rendered into the `Routes` component.

Additionally, the `Route` component API also changed. RRDv6 `Route` components only render routed content on the `element` prop. The `children` prop is only ever used for building nested routes.

## Solution

App

Wrap the routes in a `Routes` component, the spiritual successor to the RRDv5 `Switch` component. `Routes` handles the route path matching and rendering of routed content.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
        <Route path="/homepage" element={<HomeScreen />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

LandingPage

Remove the extraneous router in `LandingPage` component. It is also more common to use the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler to submit a form than an `onClick` handler on the submit button.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function LandingPage(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const auth = getAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  async function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth, email, password
      );
      navigate('/homepage');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
      console.log('Not Authorized');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
      <form onSubmit={preventDefault}>
        <h3>Login Here</h3>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Sigh up with email"
          id="username"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          id="password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className='button' type="submit" >Log In</button>
        <div className='landingpage-logo'>
          <img src={logo} className="landingpage-logo"></img>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is the issue, but I believe your `LandingPage` does not have access to the `Routes` context because your `Routes` in your `App` are defined incorrectly:

You can define which element the route has to render by using the `element` prop.

```
<Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
```

The `children` of a `Route` in `react-router` 6 are reserved for defining child routes:

```
<Route path="albums" element={<AlbumsPage />}>
  <Route path=":id" element={<AlbumPage />} />
  <Route path="add" element={<CreateAlbumPage />} />
</Route>
```

---

You can also remove the `<Routes />` component in your `LandingPage`.

---

Thirdly, the `exact` prop no longer exists on a `<Route />` in `react-router` 6. You can safely remove it. `react-router` is smart enough to know which route to render nowadays.

---

For more information on how to migrate from `react-router` 5 to `react-router` 6. Please refer to: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5